# problems with comments_number()

Tags: wp-query

Why does the following code:

```
echo '<ul>';
while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();

    $title = get_the_title();
    echo '<li>' . $title . comments_number() . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

. . . move the comments ABOVE and outside of the `<li>` like this:

1 Comment

- Hello world!

Answer (score 2):

`comments_number()` echo's the number of comments, while `get_comments_number()` returns the number of comments as a string, so what you are likely looking for is `get_comments_number` instead of `comments_number`, like

```
echo '<ul>';
while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();

    $title = get_the_title();
    echo '<li>' . $title . get_comments_number() . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_comments_number

Comment: You're missing the information that `comments_number` doesn't return the number of comments, it prints it out

Comment: @Tom J Nowell, Answer is updated